# Почему YouTubeStandalonePlayer не работает и как исправть?

Tags: youtube-android-api, youtube, android, youtube-api

Код:

```
 Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(this, DEVELOPER_KEY, VIDEO_ID);
      startActivity(intent);
```

Logcat:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Говорит что класса нету, либу подключили с ютубом?

Comment: > Говорит что класса нету

А какой класс тут нужен?

Comment: YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi
https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/

Comment: import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeStandalonePlayer; - для standalone этого хватает

Comment: Посмотрите на ошибку он как раз говорит что этого класса нету :)

Comment: Кстати, я использовал  YouTubePlayerView и там была проблему что плеер не инициализировался до тех пора пока не будет установлен акутальный клиент ютуба не телефон. Пришлось добавлять проверку на наличие свежего ютуба.

Comment: Но ведь он подключён

Comment: Возможно в встроенном виде он есть в последних версиях АПИ, а в более ранних версиях такого класса просто может не быть, о чем и говорит ошибка.

Comment: подключил, зафурычело